# KDE Plasma 5 upgrade has removed my window decorations

Tags: kde, window, plasma

Upgrading to KDE Plasma 5 today in Vivid Vervet (Wednesday 21st Jan) has removed all my window decorations such as borders, etc. I can't move windows, drag windows, etc. Any ideas how to get it back?

Comment: First thing I did was add this bug to Launchpad. But no-one has replied to it!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Here is what I typed to fix it:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure kwin
dpkg-reconfigure: kwin is broken or not fully installed
$ sudo apt-get install kwin
....
```

A few extra libraries were installed and I have Breeze decorations back again.